# How to Copy two-dimensionals arrays without knowledge about their size

Tags: java

I want to copy an array, but I don't know its size. I pasted the class and method below.

```
public MyClass {

private int map[][];

public void setMap(int[][] map){

 //my code here

    }
}
```

Of course, this way doesn't work. Because (as I said) I don't know the size.

```
int map[][] = new int[N][N];
for (int[] i : map)
for (int j : i)
i[j] = 1;
```

Comment: you might not know, but `array.length` does. Use classic `for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the number of rows in your array and columns by using the `.length()` function. You can then initialize a 2D array with the same number of rows and columns by doing the following:

```
//array.length() is the number of rows. 
//array[0].length() takes the first row and gives you the number of columns.
int map[][] = new int[array.length][array[0].length];
```

Now, to copy the array called `array`, you can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++){
        map[i][j] = array[i][j];
    }
}
```

This is how you will copy your two-dimensional array, `array`, into your new array, `map`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your line of code does not copy an array at all

Comment: I've no certainty if number of rows and columns are equal.

Comment: I have changed it. Now it copies the array, `array`, into the 2D array, `map`.

Comment: Number of columns is different than number of rows.

Comment: Then, since each row has the same number of columns, you can say `array[0].length()` to get the number of columns, since `array[0]` will give you an array, the first row. Then, `array[0].length` will give you the number of columns! This should work now!

Comment: Yes! The way to solve it was..primitive. It's little bit too late for programming. Thanks for your help

Comment: If this helped you, please consider upvoting it. You're welcome!

Comment: `length` is not a function call, it is a property, so your code should be `array.length`, not `array.length()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't actually testing the code, so I didn't quite realize that. I'll change it in my answer. But shouldn't it be `array.length()` in the for loops?